# How do I append the sum of list within given list in prolog?

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to append the sum of a list within the given list, but not getting exactly what I need with this:

```
list_sum([],[]).
list_sum([[Lname|[Lvalues|_]]|List],X):-
   sum(Lvalues,Sum),
   app([Lname,Lvalues,Sum],[Out],X),
   list_sum(List,Out).
```

Let my input be:

```
list_sum([[list1,[1,1]],[list2,[2,2]]],X).
```

My output is:

```
X = [list1, [1, 1], 2, [list2, [2, 2], 4, []]].
```

But was expecting:

```
X = [[list1, [1, 1], 2], [list2, [2, 2], 4]].
```

I showed this example for two lists, but I'm also trying to make it work for any amount of lists, including one, but my output just gets even worse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is fairly close, but there are a couple of issues.

Your base case is good (`list_sum([], []).`). The head of your recursive clause is oddly stated:

```
list_sum([[Lname|[Lvalues|_]] | List], X) :- ...
```

The head of your first argument list, `[Lname | [Lvalues|_]]` is equivalent to `[Lname, Lvalues | _]`. Since you plan a two element list as each element, `_` would always be `[]`. So then it's equivalent to `[Lname, Lvalues]`. So the head of the recursive clause becomes:

```
list_sum([[Lname, Lvalues] | List], X) :- ...
```

The next statement, `sum(Lvalues,Sum)` looks fine. The following append is incorrect:

```
app([Lname,Lvalues,Sum],[Out],X)
```

Your intention is to have `[Lname, Lvalues, Sum]` to be the head of a new list, with `Out` as a tail. That looks like, `[[Lname, Lvalues, Sum]|Out]`. But the above append will give you, `[Lname, Lvalues, Sum | Out]` which isn't the same thing. And you don't need the `app` call. Simply, `X = [[Lname, Lvalues, Sum]|Out]` will do.

Now your recursive call looks like this:

```
list_sum([[Lname, Lvalues] | List], X) :-
    sum(Lvalues, Sum),
    X = [[Lname, Lvalues, Sum]|Out],
    list_sum(List, Out).
```

Which should yield the results you're after. You can simplify this a little by including the unification of `X` directly in the head of the clause:

```
list_sum( [[Lname, Lvalues] | List], [[Lname, Lvalues, Sum]|Out]) :-
    sum(Lvalues, Sum),
    list_sum(List, Out).
```